# CAKEPHP3 form field not returning value

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Samples Table in my database. 
Here is my Association in **SamplesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
      ]);
```

In my **SamplesControler.php** add method i'm getting current User data like this:

```
$users = $this->Samples->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'), [
            'keyField' => 'id',
            'valueField' => 'name'
        ]);
        $this->set(compact('sample', 'users'));
```

In my add.ctp in Template/Samples/ i'm using this variable to show the user name like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', [
            'label' => 'Client',
            'type' => 'text',
            'disabled' => true,
            'value' => $users->name,
            'required' => true,
        ]);
```

It shows the name correctly, but when i hit submit it doesn't returns the id of the user back to the controller to save it in database. 
Since i'm very new to this framework i can't figure out if there is anything i'm doing wrong.

I've tried debug response data in my controller add method and there is no user_id in response.

if i change

```
$users->name to $users
```

in my template file, it shows all the data about that user in json format in the textfield like this:

```
{    "id": 4,    "name": "firstname lastname",    "title": "Engineer",    "street": "122",    "city": "Lahore",    "state": "Punjab",  "email_primary": "abc@gmail.com",  "created": "2016-03-04T07:45:42+0000",    "modified": "2016-03-04T09:56:17+0000"}
```

Comment: It was too much code that is why i did'nt posted here, I just posted the part i'm having problem with, I can you more. what do you want to see?

Comment: Then it displays the id of that user instead of name field and still dont save user and gives the validation error that user is required.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear on what you're wanting to do; when I "add" (`insert`) a record into the database, I usually don't have its `id` until after the database save/transaction has happened. It almost sounds like you are doing some sort of `update`, instead.

Comment: Can you come to chat room? I can show you everything you ask

Comment: I need you to clarify one thing. In the form, does the user need to type out their user's name? Or is he selecting a name from select box?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to show the logged in user's name in the textbox and to save the logged in user's id in the controller, there's no need to fetch the user data.

It's really unnecessary and might cause security issues when you're setting the user id to the template.

When you're trying to access the data of the logged in user, it's the best to keep it this way:

```
 /* For controller: */ 
 $this->Auth->user("field_name");

 /* For view: */ 
 $this->request->session()->read("Auth.User.field_name");
```

Try this:

```
  $name =  $this->request->session()->read("Auth.User.first_name")." ".  $this->session->read()->("Auth.User.last_name"); // Add this

   echo $this->Form->input('user_id', [
        'label'    => 'Client',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'disabled' => true,
        'value'    => $name, // Add this
        'required' => true,
    ]);
```

In the controller:

```
  if ($this->request->is("post")) {

      $this->request->data["user_id"] = $this->Auth->user("id"); // Add this

      /* Other code */
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD